Utilizando auth0, react y nextJS
Utilizando auth0, react y nextJS, mi problema es como puedo obtener el accessToken proveniente del inicio de sesión de usuario mediante el uso de auth0, siendo esta token necesaria para poder utilizarla y enviarla a través del header de autenticación de todas las peticiones que realizo a mi api local de mi propia aplicación. Para ello, deduzco que necesito manipular el access token desde el lado del cliente para poder setearla manualmente dentro de cada peticion HTTP a mi api local, pero no se como llegar hasta este punto.
